# If $A\cup B$ open connected with $A$ open then must $B$ be closed?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

$A,B\subset \mathbb R^2$ s.t $A\cap B=\Phi$ and $A\cup B$ is open in $\mathbb R^2.$ Given that $A$ is open and $A\cup B$ is connected then is $B$ closed or open ?

Now if , $B$ is open too then $A\cup B$  cannot be connected so $B$ must be closed.

Now one possibility of this is that $A$ is any open set and $B=A^c$ the closed set.So the union is the whole set.

If $A$ is an open disc and $B$ is just any closed disc then the union is not open.

So my question is whether there is such a thing that this case is meaningful iff $A\cup B$  is allowed to be the whole set and otherwise not.Can I prove that **union of an open set A and a closed set B can never be open in $\mathbb R^2$ unless $B=A^c$ and $A\cup B=\mathbb R\ ?$**  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, note that "open" and "closed" **aren't** the only types of set there are!

For example, let $A=\{(x, y): x^2+y^2<1\}$, and let $B=\{(x, y): 1\le x^2+y^2<2\}$. Then

- $A$ is open and connected,
- $A\cap B=\emptyset$,
- $A\cup B$ is open and connected,
- but $B$ is neither open nor closed.

---

Your second question is: if $A$ is open and connected, $A\cap B=\emptyset$, $B$ is closed, and $A\cup B$ is open and connected, must $B=A^c$?

The answer to this is **no**: take $A=\{(x, y): 0<x^2+y^2<1\}$ and $B=\{(0, 0)\}$. (Thanks to Eric Wofsey for pointing out how silly my previous answer was - I was using *simple* connectedness!)

Comment: @EricWofsey Derp. Fixed, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Let $A=(0,1)\times(0,1)$ and $B=(0,1)\times[1,2)$; then $A\cup B=(0,1)\times(0,2)$ is open and connected, as is $A$, and $A\cap B=\varnothing$, but $B$ is neither closed nor open.

Comment: I am not getting Why does $A\cup B =(0,1) \times (0,2)?$

My thinking :  $(0,1)  \cap [1,2)=\emptyset \implies (0,1) \cup [1,2) \neq (0,2)$

Comment: @jasmine: That implication is false: $(0,1)\cup[1,2)$ **is** $(0,2)$. If $x\in(0,2)$, then $0<x<2$. Now there are two cases: either $x<1$, in which case $x\in(0,1)$, or $x\ge 1$, in which case $x\in[1,2)$. Thus, $(0,2)\subseteq(0,1)\cup[1,2)$. Clearly $(0,1)\cup[1,2)\subseteq(0,2)$, so $(0,1)\cup[1,2)=(0,2)$.

Comment: okay Sir@Brian M scott  It means that  if we take $(1,2)$ instead of $[1,2)$ then $(0,1) \cup (1,2) \neq (0,2)$.Am I right ?

Comment: @jasmine: Yes, this time you’re right, because $1\in(0,2)$, but $1\notin(0,1)\cup(1,2)$.